# .NET insert data from SQL Server to MySQL without looping through data

Tags: mysql, .net, dapper

I'm working a .NET app where the user selects some filters like date, id, etc.

What I need to do is query a SQL Server database table with those filters, and dump them into a MySQL table. I don't need all fields in the table, only a few.

So far, I need to loop through all records in the SQL Server Dataset and insert them one by one on my MySQL table.

Is there anyway of achieving better performance? I've been playing with Dapper but cant figure out a way to do something like:

```
Insert into MySQLTable (a,b,c)
Select a,b,c from SQLServerTable
where a=X and b=C
```

Any ideas?

Linked server option is not possible because we have no access to the SQL server configuration, so looking for the most efficient way of bulk inserting data.

Comment: SQL Server can link to a MySQL server making your example query a reality: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4570/access-mysql-data-from-sql-server-via-a-linked-server/

Comment: You need to create a DBlink

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this inside .NET with dapper I'd use c# and do the following;

assumptions:

a table in both tables with the same schema;

```
CREATE Events (
EventId int,
EventName varchar(10));
```

A .Net class

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

The snippet below should give you something you can use as a base.

```
    List<Event> Events = new List<Event>();

    var sqlInsert = "Insert into events( EventId, EventName ) values (@EventId, @EventName)";

    using (IDbConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Sqlconstr))
    {
        sqlconn.Open();

        Events = sqlconn.Query<Event>("Select * from events").ToList();

        using (IDbConnection mySqlconn = new SqlConnection(Sqlconstr))
        {
            mySqlconn.Open();

            mySqlconn.Execute(sqlInsert, Events);
        }
    }
```

The snippet above selects the rows from the events table in SQL Server and populates the Events list. normally Dapper will return an IEnumerable<>, but you are casting that ToList(). Now with the Events list, you connect to MySQL and execute the insert statements against the Events list. 
This snippet is just a barebones example. Without a transaction on the Execute, each row will be autocommitted. If you add a Transaction, it will commit when all the items in the Events list are inserted.

Of course there are disadvantages doing it this way. One important thing to realize is that if you are trying to insert 1million rows from SQL to MySQL, that list will contain 1million entries which will increase the memory footprint. In those cases I'd use Dapper's Buffered = false option. This will return the 1million rows 1 row at a time. Your c# code can them enumerate over the results and add the row to a list and keep a counter. after 1000 rows have been inserted into list you can do the insert part into MySQL then clear the list and contine enumerating over the rows.

this will keep the memory footprint of your application small while processing a large number of rows.

With all that said, nothing beats bulk insert at the server level.

-HTH